# AutoHotKey: How to select listbox item by it's text

Tags: autohotkey

Question in subj.
I have window, and I have ListBox on it. I wanna find particular list item and make it selected.
I've read this
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/17534-selecting-an-item-in-a-listbox/
but it doesn't work - my list dont change selection on key pressing.
So, I need to find item by text in some column and then select it (by clicking or smth else).

Comment: Does your script know the complete content of the listbox?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: yes, I know all the content, but it could be filtered and differently sorted

Comment: @MCL I even dont know where to start. I have some script but it just can find windows and press buttons, I have no idea how to work with ListBox except ControlSend, but it doesn't help because ListBox doesn't react to key pressing.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what *doesn't work* if you haven't tried anything?

Comment: I dont know how to find ListBox element in third-patry app by it text. Only samples that I've found are about creating own ListBoxes through GUI.